# Use Union All & Order By In View?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-order-by, union-all

I need to order by a date column contained in both of my tables in my view.  Below is the syntax I use for my view, but if I try to use the order by statement in the view I get this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TransFund_Lead_Upload_File, Line 63
>
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and   subqueries, unless TOP is also specified.

This is my query syntax..what needs to be altered so that I can order by [Follow Up] Desc?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
Select
'abcd' As [P]
,ISNULL(Building_Name,'') As [Building_Name]
,ISNULL(ID,'') As [Record ID]
,ISNULL(city,'') + ', ' + ISNULL([state],'') As [Zone]
,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Sale Date], 101),'') As [Actual Sale Date]
,'' As [Begin Effort]
,ISNULL(CAST(sold_items AS VARCHAR(500)),'') As [Items List]
,ISNULL(CAST(wascoreItemSold AS Varchar(500)),'') As [Info]
,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), followupdate, 101),'') As [Follow Up]
FROM dbo.esrt b
UNION ALL
Select
'eeee' As [P]
,ISNULL(Building_Name,'') As [Building_Name]
,ISNULL(ID,'') As [Record ID]
,ISNULL(city,'') + ', ' + ISNULL([state],'') As [Zone]
,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Sale Date, 101),'') As [Actual Sale Date]
,'' As [Begin Effort]
,ISNULL(CAST(sold_items AS Varchar(500)),'') As [Items List]
,ISNULL(CAST(wascoreItemSold AS Varchar(500)),'') As [Info]
,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), followupdate, 101),'') As [Follow Up]
FROM dbo.foxtrot a
) a
ORDER BY a.[Follow Up] DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since views are treated like sub-queries the sort would force extra work.  SQL Server will automatically sort data from tables or views to optimize looking up your results which is why results can come back in a random order.  Any filters and sorts on the query using the view would negate your view's sort clause.  Also, depending on what your view is doing, SQL Server might choose to pull the view's contents up into the main query so it can be further optimized in a single query plan.

Keep in mind, SQL Server itself does not care about the order it receives or delivers results. The TOP statement tells SQL Server that there is a definitive reason for needing to sort the records as it will affect the results returned.

You'll have to sort when you select your results from your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
ORDER BY [Follow Up] DESC;
```